# Why does not work if statement php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**index.js**

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'php_action/getSelectedMember.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {member_id : id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
                $("#Number1").text(response.num1);
)}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $var="10";
    $result='<p id="Number1"></p>';
    echo gettype($result) , gettype($var); //string,string
    echo "$result $var"; // 10,10
    if ($result == $var) {
        echo "OK!";
    }
?>
```

value `Number1` is 10, and variables `$var` and `$result` are the type of string. does not work if statement in index.php? Is there another way to get `id Number1` value?

Comment: because $resul and $var are not equal ... one is "10" and the other is "<p id='number1'>....

Comment: well ... `'<p id="Number1"></p>'` will never equal `"10"` - the two strings are hardcoded, and wont magically change to be equal ... I can't see how `echo "$result $var";` could possibly in this universe result in "10,10" - where does the comma even come from (let alone the changed value of $result)

Comment: the html render dont show the tag ... but the code is inside the string . however

Comment: What/how does that AJAX call have to do with anything?

Comment: What exactly are you doing here?

1. You specify the result to be expected as json in js, but you return partial HTML in the PHP file.

2. Where do you use number1 and how do you think it gets to the client? You echo '<p id="Number 1"></p> 10', what are you expecting?

Also, why didn't you test the PHP file via a web browser to locate the problem?

Comment: `echo "$result $var";` will never ever outputs `10,10`.See here:-https://eval.in/826451

Comment: Pages and codes are many. All the codes are in the link : [link](http://codersfolder.com/2016/07/crud-with-php-mysqli-bootstrap-datatables-jquery-plugin/) , I want to use the value id Number1 in the php page. Also Nothing is received index.php. (dont works $_POST , $_GET)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your index.php. when you use dataType JSON then first echo will return.try to avoid echo. '< p id="Number1">< / p >' will never equal "10" but you can try in this way, i think it will help you.

```
<?php
  $var='10';
  $result='10';
  $array = array();

  if ($result == $var) {
    $array['msg'] = 'OK!'
  }

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php
    $var="10";
    $result='<p id="Number1"></p>';
    echo gettype($result) , gettype($var); //string,string
    echo "$result $var"; // 10,10
    if ( strcmp($result, $var) ){
        echo "OK!";
    }
?>
```